# Number of microstates for a specific energy for $N$-particle system subdividing energy into small intervals

Tags: energy, statistical-mechanics

I was reading a part of Reif's Statistical Physics book that said that the number of microstates for a system containing $N$ particle and energy $E$ is proportional to $δE$ but I am confused here. if we subdivide the energy scale into equal small ranges of magnitude δE, the accurate expression for the number of microstates for an N-particle system with energy E would be the number of ways this system can occupy energy E. which is:
$$\Omega(E)={\frac{E}{δE}+N-1\choose N-1}\approx{\frac{E}{δE}+N\choose\frac{E}{δE}}=\frac{(\frac{E}{δE}+N)!}{\frac{E}{δE}! \space N!} .$$
And it's not proportional to δE like what Reif said in the book. is it anything wrong with my statement?
$$$$
Also here's what exactly is written in the book:

[image]

Comment: Where did you get $\frac{E}{δE}$ in your calculations? Are you considering the system where each particle is constrained to having only $\frac{E}{δE}$ energy?

Comment: You left off the important footnote (which probably shouldn't be a footnote): "The number of states $\Omega(E)$ must vanish as $\delta E\to0$ and must be expressible as a Taylor's series in powers of $\delta E$. When $\delta E$ is sufficiently small, all terms involving higher powers of $\delta E$ are negligibly small and one is left with an expression of the form (2.5.1)." As to why it doesn't match *your* expression, perhaps you can edit your post to include your reasoning, so that we can understand your statement.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the authour simply hinted at the derivative. But didn't explain his intentions that carefully and used a little bit confusing notation. Read the * note at the end of the page. The Taylor expansion is mentioned.

## 1) The math of Taylor expansion

This is because whenever we write

$\Omega'(E) = \displaystyle\lim_{\Delta E \to 0} \frac{\Omega(E+\Delta E) - \Omega(E)}{\Delta E}$ $\;(1)\;$, where $\Omega (E)$ is [analytic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function) (basically, can be expanded as Taylor's series),

we can write $\Omega'(E) = \displaystyle\lim_{\Delta E \to 0} \frac{(\Omega(E) + \Omega'(E) \Delta E \; +\text{the rest of Taylor expansion, terms of order }(\Delta E)^2)- \Omega(E)}{\Delta E}$

Now let
$\underline{\boldsymbol{d\Omega=\Omega'(E) \; d E}} = \Omega'(E) \Delta E \; +\text{the rest of Taylor expansion, terms of order }(\Delta E)^2$,

$\Delta E = dE$.

And let's use the above notation **only to note the limit process being taken as in $(1)$**.
Thus, whenever we have an expression of the form $\;d\Omega=A \; d E\;$ it simply means that $A = \Omega'(E)$ and we may interpret $\Delta E$ as **infinitesimal increase in $E$** since we agreed to use the notaion only to imply the limiting process, where $\Delta E \to 0$. And $\;d\Omega\;$ is then the **infinitesimal increase in $\Omega$**.

## 2) Back to the statement about number of states

With all the theory behind, I think the author meant the following:

$\boldsymbol{\Omega(E)}$ that corresponds to *sufficiently small* interval of energy $\boldsymbol{\delta E}$ corresponds to a *relatively small increase* in $\Omega$ — the very $\boldsymbol{d\Omega}$ we discussed above, that corresponds to a *relatively small increase* in $E$ — the $\boldsymbol{dE}$ as above.

This way we also can **approximate** the number of states $\Delta \Omega$ corresponding to energy interval $[E,\; E+dE]$, where $dE$ is not infinitesimal, like this:

$$\Delta \Omega \approx \Omega'(E) \Delta E\,$$
, as we do with any other derivative.

## 3) Finally

The density of states is merely defined as:

$$\omega(E) = \Omega'(E)$$

And the following approximation may take place:

$$\Delta \Omega \approx \omega(E) \Delta E\,$$

Where all the definitions were discussed earlier in this post.
$\rule[0.5cm]{20cm}{0.6pt}$
The author likely meant the same thing, but seemingly left out *a few* details.

Comment: yes, I read that but I don't believe if δE tends to zero, Ω would vanish. I think it should be infinity (according to combination form that I said)

Comment: It does not technichally vanish, it's the infinitesimal correspondance I defined. I didn't understand your combination argument, can you explain it?

Comment: Read my comment to your question